# Kotlin Goal Oriented Action Planning

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I've implemented Goal Oriented Action Planning (GOAP) in Kotlin.

Goal Oriented Action Planning is an algorithm originally devised by J Orkin for the game F.E.A.R. and performs a state space search using A* in order to formulate a plan of actions to get from an initial state to a goal state.

I've commented the code comprehensively and written some tests.

I'm looking for a code review to make sure my naming is good, my comments are good and that overall it makes sense.

```
import org.junit.Test
import java.lang.Math.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.HashSet
import kotlin.test.assertFalse
import kotlin.test.assertTrue


/**
 * This set of algorithms is an example of a Goal Oriented Action Planner (aka GOAP)
 *
 * Goal Oriented Action Planning (GOAP) is a method of planning developed by J Orkin for the game F.E.A.R.
 * It can be conceptualized in a few ways - I like to think of it as dynamically calculated FSM
 * as you do not need to explicitly write the state transition table and it is instead calculated at run time
 * by searching through states given a set of actions. In other words GOAP is a state space search algorithm that outputs plans.
 * You can read more about GOAP here: http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~jorkin/goap.html
 *
 * First there is an implementation of A* which is the basis for the state space search
 * I have also implemented simple Cartesian graph search to show the extensibility of the A* implementation
 *
 * The idea with GOAP is that you would have many agents in an environment, and each agent has sensors that update a state that the agent maintains
 * The agents will then be able to formulate a plan of actions, given a goal state and their current state by using the GOAP algorith
 * This plan would then be actuated by actuators which in turn would then affect the environment, causing the sensors to update the agents state
 * This process continues in a feedback loop so the agents should be able to act autonomously within any given environment.
 *
 * In other words, this solution can be used for games, robotics or even abstract problem domains such as shipping systems
 * Where plans must be formulated based on dynamically changing conditions
 *
 * The plans generated by this particular implementation of GOAP are totally ordered
 * In future, work will be undertaken to modify this solution so that it can generate partially ordered plans
 * But that is a much more challenging problem to solve as partially ordered plans would require a completely different approach than A*
 */


/**
 * Searches for the shortest path [from] -> [to] and returns a [Stack] of [AStarNode] representing the path (i.e. this is A*)
 * By applying [heuristic] and [cost] for each evaluated open node to calculate the f cost to the goal
 * This is non greedy BFS so long as [heuristic] is admissible (i.e. never overestimates)
 * For example, in the case of 2D geometric search, the [heuristic] can be considered admissible if it measures euclidean distance
 * In addition [from] and [to] should be part of either an oriented or bi directional graph which can be navigated via calling [neighbours] on a given [AStarNode]
 */
fun<T> path(from: AStarNode<T>,
            to: AStarNode<T>,
            heuristic: ((AStarNode<T>, AStarNode<T>) -> Int),
            cost: ((AStarNode<T>, AStarNode<T>) -> Int)) : Stack<AStarNode<T>> {

    /**
     * Reconstructs a path, represented as a [Stack] of [AStarNode]
     * By updating a pointer to a node until the pointer points at null
     */
    fun reconstructPath(from: AStarNode<T>) : Stack<AStarNode<T>> {
        val path = mutableListOf<AStarNode<T>>()
        var current: AStarNode<T>? = from
        path.add(current!!)
        while (current?.from !== null) {
            path.add(current.from!!)
            current = current.from
        }
        path.reverse()
        return Stack<AStarNode<T>>().apply {
            path.forEach { this.push(it) }
        }
    }

    // Use a priority queue for maintaining the open boundary of the search
    // This means the search will always expand the optimal edge of the border
    val openQueue = PriorityQueue<AStarNode<T>>()

    // Use a hash set for the closed nodes to increase performance on big graphs
    val closedSet = HashSet<AStarNode<T>>()

    // The g cost of the initial node is by definition 0
    from.g = 0

    // The heuristic cost of the initial node is the heuristic function applied to it and the goal
    from.f = heuristic(from, to)

    // Of course, the initial node is the only node on the open border of the search before searching
    openQueue.offer(from)

    // Begin the search
    // While there are still nodes to explore on the open border
    while (!openQueue.isEmpty()) {
        // Get the highest priority node
        val current = openQueue.poll()

        // Check if we've reached the goal node
        if (current == to)
            return reconstructPath(current)

        // Ok, we still need to search
        // Add the node to the closed set so we don't evaluate it again
        closedSet.add(current)

        // For each neighbour of the node calculate it's g cost and update it's from pointer
        current.neighbours().forEach { neighbour ->
            // If the neighbour is in the closed set ignore it
            if (closedSet.contains(neighbour))
                return@forEach

            // Calc a new g score
            val tentativeG = current.g + cost(current, neighbour)

            // Push the neighbour into the open border if it's not already there
            // If it is already there and has a lower g cost then ignore it
            if (!openQueue.contains(neighbour)) {
                openQueue.offer(neighbour)
            } else if (tentativeG >= neighbour.g) {
                return@forEach
            }

            // We've found a shorter path
            // Update the neighbours from pointer and costs
            neighbour.from = current
            neighbour.g = tentativeG
            neighbour.f = neighbour.g + heuristic(neighbour, to)
        }
    }

    // The open border was exhaustively checked, no path exists!
    throw IllegalArgumentException("No path can be found from $from to $to")
}

/**
 * Parameterized type which wraps some [data] along with a pointer to the [from] node and [g] and [f] costs used in A* search
 * The type argument [T] means that A* can be performed for any type as long as there is an admissable heuristic calculable for the type [T]
 */
abstract class AStarNode<T>(val data: T?,
                            var from: AStarNode<T>? = null,
                            var g: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
                            var f: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE) : Comparable<AStarNode<T>> {

    /**
     * Returns a [Collection] of neighbour nodes
     * In the case of euclidean nodes this is simply the connected nodes on the graph
     * In the case of non euclidean nodes this could be a function of any number of things
     * For instance, in a state space search, this could return any states which were transition to from valid actions
     */
    abstract fun neighbours() : Collection<AStarNode<T>>

    /**
     * Implemented so these can be used in a priority queue
     */
    override fun compareTo(other: AStarNode<T>): Int {
        return when {
            this.f < other.f -> -1
            this.f > other.f -> 1
            else -> 0
        }
    }
}

/**
 * An implementation of [AStarNode] for cartesian space search
 * A cartesian space search takes place on a 2D plane through a oriented or bi-direction graph of points in space
 * A point in cartesian space is defined by an [x] and a [y] value and, in this case, also has an associated [label]
 */
class CartesianNode(val x: Int,
                    val y: Int,
                    label: String,
                    private val neighbours: MutableCollection<CartesianNode> = mutableListOf()) : AStarNode<String>(label) {

    /**
     * Distance to another node is euclidean and worked out using pythagorean theorem
     */
    fun distanceTo(other: CartesianNode) : Int {
        val dx = abs(this.x - other.x).toDouble()
        val dy = abs(this.y - other.y).toDouble()
        return round(sqrt(dx * dx) + sqrt(dy * dy)).toInt()
    }

    /**
     * Used to add an [other] neighbour
     */
    fun addNeighbour(other: CartesianNode) {
        this.neighbours.add(other)
    }

    /**
     * Implement the neighbours functionality by simply returning an immutable copy of the neighbours list
     */
    override fun neighbours(): Collection<AStarNode<String>> {
        return this.neighbours.toList()
    }

    /**
     * A cartesian node is equal to another one if the coordinates are the same
     */
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return if (other !is CartesianNode) {
            false
        } else {
            this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implement hash code so this can be used in a hash set
     */
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var hash = 7
        hash = 31 * hash + g
        hash = 31 * hash + f
        hash = 31 * hash + data.hashCode()
        return hash
    }
}

/**
 * Wraps [findPath] providing functions for the heuristic and cost in cartesian space
 */
class CartesianPathfinder {
    fun findPath(from: CartesianNode, to: CartesianNode) = path(from, to, { x, y ->
        (x as CartesianNode).distanceTo(y as CartesianNode)
    }, { x, y ->
        (x as CartesianNode).distanceTo(y as CartesianNode)
    })
}

/**
 * An implementation of [AStarNode] for state space search
 * A state space search occurs in an abstract space where points within that space represent states
 * and edges between the point represent actions taken to reach a state from a state
 * A point in state space search is defined by a [worldState] and keep a reference to an [actionPool] of possible [GoapAction]
 * These also keep a reference to the [actionTaken] to reach the state
 */
class GoapNode(val worldState: WorldState,
               private val actionPool: Collection<GoapAction>,
               actionTaken: GoapAction? = null) : AStarNode<GoapAction>(actionTaken) {

    /**
     * Implementation of neighbours for state space search
     * Neighbours in this case are other states which can be reached by applying all possible valid actions to this state
     */
    override fun neighbours(): Collection<AStarNode<GoapAction>> {
        // For all actions in the action pool
        // If they are valid, apply the action to this state, otherwise ignore it
        return actionPool.mapNotNull { action ->
            if (action.isValid(worldState)) {
                GoapNode(worldState.applyAction(action), actionPool, action)
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Goap nodes are equal if the amount of differences between the states is 0
     */
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return if (other !is GoapNode) {
            false
        } else {
            this.worldState.countDifferences(other.worldState) == 0
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implement hash code so that these can be used in a hash set
     */
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var hash = 7
        hash = 31 * hash + g
        hash = 31 * hash + f
        hash = 31 * hash + data.hashCode()
        return hash
    }
}

/**
 * An action is defined primarily by [preconditions], [postConditions] and a name
 * An action can be applied to a [WorldState] if the given [WorldState] satisifes the actions [preconditions]
 * The result of applying an action to a [WorldState] is the state of the world will be modified by applying the [postConditions] of the action
 * When performing state space search, the action also has procedural checks performed to validate if it is not only statically valid but also dynamically valid
 * This is achieved by running the [isProcedurallyValid] function at plan time (when working out the neighbours of world states)
 * Actions can be also be determined to be dynamically complete via the [isComplete] function and can be executed in an environment using the [execute] function
 */
data class GoapAction(val name: String,
                      val preconditions: Map<String, Boolean>,
                      val postConditions: Map<String, Boolean>,
                      val cost: Int,
                      val isProcedurallyValid: ((GoapAgent) -> Boolean),
                      val isComplete: ((GoapAgent) -> Boolean),
                      val execute: ((GoapAgent) -> Unit))

/**
 * Returns true if an action is valid [forWorldState]
 */
fun GoapAction.isValid(forWorldState: WorldState) : Boolean {
    return forWorldState.isActionValid(this)
}

/**
 * Define the contract for a planning agent
 * This can be implemented for any number of environments
 * Be it games, robotics or any other abstract domain
 */
interface GoapAgent {
    val blackboard: Blackboard
    fun hasPlan(): Boolean
    fun plan()
    fun onActionCompleted(fromAction: GoapAction)
}

/**
 * A world state is simply a [Map] of facts about the world
 * Facts are binary and have an associated name
 * for instance:
 * HasMoney = false
 * HasReachedTarget = true
 */
data class WorldState(val state: Map<String, Boolean>)

/**
 * Returns a [WorldState] by applying [action] to source [WorldState]
 */
fun WorldState.applyAction(action: GoapAction) : WorldState {
    return WorldState(this.state.toMutableMap().apply {
        this.putAll(action.postConditions)
    })
}

/**
 * Returns the number of differences between the source [WorldState] and the [against] state
 */
fun WorldState.countDifferences(against: WorldState) : Int {
    // Fold the against state into an integer representing the differences
    return against.state.keys.fold(0) { acc, key ->
        acc + when (val prop = this.state[key]) {
            null -> 1
            else -> when (prop == against.state[key]) {
                true -> 0
                else -> 1
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a copy of the source [WorldState] with the updated [value] for the given [variable]
 */
fun WorldState.setStateVariable(variable: String, value: Boolean) : WorldState {
    return WorldState(this.state.toMutableMap().apply { this[variable] = value })
}

/**
 * Returns true if the [action] is valid for the source [WorldState]
 */
fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction) : Boolean {
    // Fold the actions preconditions into an integer representing the unsatisfied variables
    // And return true if the unsatisfied variables are 0 else false
    return action.preconditions.keys.fold(0) { acc, key ->
        acc + when (val prop = this.state[key]) {
            null -> 1
            else -> {
                when (prop == action.preconditions[key]) {
                    true -> 0
                    else -> 1
                }
            }
        }
    } == 0
}

/**
 * A blackboard maintains a state of the world and has references to sensors and actuators
 * An agent has a reference to a blackboard, which can be though of as the agents central system for sensing, remember and actuating in an environment
 */
class Blackboard(private val world: WorldState) {
    fun updateState(variable: String, value: Boolean) {
        this.world.setStateVariable(variable, value)
    }
}

/**
 * Wraps [path] providing state search specific heuristic and cost functions
 */
class GoapPlanner {
    fun plan(actionPool: Collection<GoapAction>, fromState: WorldState, toState: WorldState) = Stack<GoapAction>().apply {
        this.addAll(
            path(
                GoapNode(fromState, actionPool, null),
                GoapNode(toState, actionPool, null),
                { a, b ->
                    (a as GoapNode).worldState.countDifferences((b as GoapNode).worldState)
                }, { _, b ->
                    (b as GoapNode).data?.cost ?: 0
                }
            ).mapNotNull { goapNode ->
                goapNode.data
            }
        )
    }
}

/**
 * Provides a clean API to execute plans that an [agent] has formulated
 */
class PlanExecutor(private val agent: GoapAgent,
                   private val plan: Stack<GoapAction>) {

    /**
     * Returns true if the plan is not empty
     */
    fun hasPlan() = plan.isNotEmpty()

    /**
     * Checks if the action on top of the stack is complete
     * If it is, it pops the stack
     * It then performs [execute] on the action on top of the stack
     */
    fun execute() {
        if (this.plan.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (this.plan.peek().isComplete(this.agent)) {
                agent.onActionCompleted(this.plan.pop() as GoapAction)
            } else {
                this.plan.peek().execute(this.agent)
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Set of tests for validating the correctness of the GOAP algorithm
 */
class GoapTests {
    @Test
    fun testSimplePath() {
        // Make a 2 node bi-directional graph
        val a = CartesianNode(0, 0, "a")
        val b = CartesianNode(10, 10, "b")
        a.addNeighbour(b)
        b.addNeighbour(a)

        // Create a cartesian pathfinder
        val pathfinder = CartesianPathfinder()

        // Find a path from a -> b
        val path = pathfinder.findPath(a, b)

        // Assert that the path is of length 2
        // And that it goes a -> b
        assertTrue { path.size == 2 }
        assertTrue { path[0] == a }
        assertTrue { path[1] == b }
    }

    @Test
    fun testComplexPath() {
        // Make a more complicated bi-directional graph
        val a = CartesianNode(0, 0, "a")
        val b = CartesianNode(10, 10, "b")
        val c = CartesianNode(20, 10, "c")
        val d = CartesianNode(20, 20, "d")
        val e = CartesianNode(30, 10, "e")

        // Doubly link all the nodes
        a.addNeighbour(b)
        b.addNeighbour(a)
        b.addNeighbour(c)
        b.addNeighbour(d)
        c.addNeighbour(b)
        c.addNeighbour(e)
        d.addNeighbour(b)
        d.addNeighbour(e)
        e.addNeighbour(c)
        e.addNeighbour(d)

        // Create a cartesian pathfindr
        val pathfinder = CartesianPathfinder()

        // Find a path from a -> e
        val path = pathfinder.findPath(a, e)

        // Assert that the path is of length 4
        // And that the path is a -> b -> c -> e
        assertTrue { path.size == 4 }
        assertTrue { path[0] == a }
        assertTrue { path[1] == b }
        assertTrue { path[2] == c }
        assertTrue { path[3] == e }
    }

    @Test
    fun testSimplePlan() {
        // Create an initial state where HasBread is false
        val initialState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasBread", false)
        ))

        // Create a desired state where HasBread is true
        val goalState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasBread", true)
        ))

        // Create a pool of actions
        // In this case, there is 1 action "GetBread"
        // That has no preconditions and a single postcondition where HasBread becomes true
        val getBreadAction = GoapAction(
            name = "GetBread",
            preconditions = emptyMap(),
            postConditions = mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true)),
            cost = 5,
            isProcedurallyValid = { true },
            isComplete = { true },
            execute = { })

        val actionPool = listOf(getBreadAction)

        // Create a GOAP planner
        val planner = GoapPlanner()

        // Find a plan of actions that take us from the initial state to the desired state
        val plan = planner.plan(actionPool, initialState, goalState)

        assertTrue { plan.size == 1 }
        assertTrue { plan.peek() == getBreadAction }
    }

    @Test
    fun testComplexPlan() {
        // Create an initial state where all variables are false
        val initialState = WorldState(mutableMapOf())

        // Create a desired state where HasToast is true
        val goalState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasToast", true)
        ))

        // Define some more complex actions
        // With preconditions and postconditions
        val workForMoneyAction = GoapAction(
            name = "WorkForMoney",
            preconditions = emptyMap(),
            postConditions = mapOf(Pair("HasMoney", true)),
            cost = 5,
            isProcedurallyValid = { true },
            isComplete = { true },
            execute = { })

        val getBreadAction = GoapAction(
            name = "GetBread",
            preconditions = mapOf(Pair("HasMoney", true)),
            postConditions = mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true), Pair("HasMoney", false)),
            cost = 5,
            isProcedurallyValid = { true },
            isComplete = { true },
            execute = { })

        val makeToastAction = GoapAction(
            name = "MakeToast",
            preconditions = mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true)),
            postConditions = mapOf(Pair("HasToast", true), Pair("HasBread", false)),
            cost = 5,
            isProcedurallyValid = { true },
            isComplete =  { true },
            execute = { })

        // Create the action pool
        val actionPool = listOf(
            workForMoneyAction,
            getBreadAction,
            makeToastAction
        )

        // Create the planner
        val planner = GoapPlanner()

        // Find a plan to take us from the initial state to the desired state of having toast
        val plan = planner.plan(actionPool, initialState, goalState)

        // Assert that the plan is of length 3 and has the correct actions in the correct order
        assertTrue { plan.size == 3 }
        assertTrue { plan.pop() == makeToastAction }
        assertTrue { plan.pop() == getBreadAction }
        assertTrue { plan.pop() == workForMoneyAction }
    }

    @Test
    fun testWorldStateDiffWhenStatesAreSame() {
        val a = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasBread", true)
        ))

        val b = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasBread", true)
        ))

        assertTrue { a.countDifferences(b) == 0 }
    }

    @Test
    fun testWorldStateDiffWhenStatesAreDifferent() {
        val a = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasBread", true)
        ))

        val b = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasBread", false)
        ))

        assertTrue { a.countDifferences(b) == 1 }
    }

    @Test
    fun testWorldStateDiffForDifferingLengthStateMaps() {
        val a = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasBread", false),
            Pair("HasMoney", true)
        ))

        val b = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasBread", true)
        ))

        assertTrue { a.countDifferences(b) == 1 }
    }

    @Test
    fun testActionIsNotValidForWorldState() {
        val forState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasMoney", false)
        ))

        val action = GoapAction("GetBread", mapOf(Pair("HasMoney", true)), mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true)), 5, { true }, { true }, { })

        assertFalse { action.isValid(forState) }
    }

    @Test
    fun testActionIsValidForWorldState() {
        val forState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasMoney", true)
        ))

        val action = GoapAction("GetBread", mapOf(Pair("HasMoney", true)), mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true)), 5, { true }, { true }, { })

        assertTrue { action.isValid(forState) }
    }

    @Test
    fun testMakeToastIsInvalidForHasBreadFalseWorldState() {
        val makeToast = GoapAction("MakeToast", mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true)), mapOf(Pair("HasToast", true), Pair("HasBread", false)), 5, { true }, { true }, { })

        val forState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasToast", false),
            Pair("HasBread", false),
            Pair("HasMoney", true)
        ))

        val isValid = makeToast.isValid(forState)

        assertTrue { !isValid }
    }

    @Test
    fun testApplyAction() {
        val initialState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasMoney", true)
        ))

        val action = GoapAction("GetBread", mapOf(Pair("HasMoney", true)), mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true)), 5, { true }, { true }, { })

        val expectedWorldState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasMoney", true),
            Pair("HasBread", true)
        ))

        val resultingWorldState = initialState.applyAction(action)

        assertTrue { resultingWorldState == expectedWorldState }
    }

    @Test
    fun testGoapNodeNeighboursSimple() {
        val actionPool = listOf(
            GoapAction("WorkForMoney", emptyMap(), mapOf(Pair("HasMoney", true)), 5, { true }, { true }, { }),
            GoapAction("GetBread", mapOf(Pair("HasMoney", true)), mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true), Pair("HasMoney", false)), 5, { true }, { true }, { }),
            GoapAction("MakeToast", mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true)), mapOf(Pair("HasToast", true), Pair("HasBread", false)), 5, { true }, { true }, { })
        )

        val forState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasToast", false),
            Pair("HasBread", false),
            Pair("HasMoney", false)
        ))

        val node = GoapNode(forState, actionPool)

        val neighbours = node.neighbours()

        assertTrue { neighbours.size == 1 }
    }

    @Test
    fun testGoapNodeNeighboursComplex() {
        val actionPool = listOf(
            GoapAction("WorkForMoney", emptyMap(), mapOf(Pair("HasMoney", true)), 5, { true }, { true }, { }),
            GoapAction("GetBread", mapOf(Pair("HasMoney", true)), mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true), Pair("HasMoney", false)), 5, { true }, { true }, { }),
            GoapAction("MakeToast", mapOf(Pair("HasBread", true)), mapOf(Pair("HasToast", true), Pair("HasBread", false)), 5, { true }, { true }, { })
        )

        val forState = WorldState(mutableMapOf(
            Pair("HasToast", false),
            Pair("HasBread", false),
            Pair("HasMoney", true)
        ))

        val node = GoapNode(forState, actionPool)

        val neighbours = node.neighbours()

        assertTrue { neighbours.size == 2 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite a lot to analyze, so I will focus only few examples on semantics, best practices and language features.

## Naming

### Good:

- Have a structure
- well understandable
- not too long

### Arguable:

Some of your parameter and field names are way too short.

```
abstract class AStarNode<T>(val data: T?,
                            var from: AStarNode<T>? = null,
                            var g: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
                            var f: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE) : Comparable<AStarNode<T>> {
```

`g`, `f`

```
fun distanceTo(other: CartesianNode) : Int {
    val dx = abs(this.x - other.x).toDouble()
    val dy = abs(this.y - other.y).toDouble()
    return round(sqrt(dx * dx) + sqrt(dy * dy)).toInt()
}
```

`dx`, `dy` are arguable, because I can understand them through method name.

## Comments

Very many of them - although they are well understandable, I'm a fan when the number of code lines is much bigger than the comment lines.

A best practice is to use comments to describe the reason for something not obvious or complex - not the implementation.

### Good:

Very good example of yours, where a comment says WHY and not WHAT:

```
/**
 * Implemented so these can be used in a priority queue
 */
override fun compareTo(other: AStarNode<T>): Int
```

### Arguable:

Many comments could be left out, because ...

- they are obvious

  ```
  // Begin the search
  ```

  ```
  /**
   * Implement hash code so that these can be used in a hash set
   */
  override fun hashCode(): Int {
      var hash = 7
      hash = 31 * hash + g
      hash = 31 * hash + f
      hash = 31 * hash + data.hashCode()
      return hash
  }
  ```
- commenting a setter - I don't see any need here for a comment

  ```
  // The g cost of the initial node is by definition 0
  from.g = 0
  ```
- tell me something I could have figured out in 2 seconds looking into the code

  ```
  /**
   * A cartesian node is equal to another one if the coordinates are the same
   */
  override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
      return if (other !is CartesianNode) {
          false
      } else {
          this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y
      }
  }
  ```

  ```
  /**
   * Returns true if the plan is not empty
   */
  fun hasPlan() = plan.isNotEmpty()
  ```

If you have to explain in the code how your method works (not necessarily classes), its neither well written, nor has it an understandable name.

```
// For each neighbour of the node calculate it's g cost and update it's from pointer
```

I strongly believe that comments can, and often do, pollute source code. The goal should be to write the code so well, that it explains itself.

## Language features

### Good:

Almost nothing to complain about. You seem to get along with kotlin.

### Arguable:

Some things are a bit more complex than they could be, or miss some existing helping functionalities:

```
override fun compareTo(other: AStarNode<T>): Int {
    return when {
        this.f < other.f -> -1
        this.f > other.f -> 1
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

can be

```
override fun compareTo(other: AStarNode<T>): Int = this.f.compareTo(other.f)
```

```
override fun hashCode(): Int {
    var hash = 7
    hash = 31 * hash + g
    hash = 31 * hash + f
    hash = 31 * hash + data.hashCode()
    return hash
}
```

can be

```
 override fun hashCode(): Int = HashCodeBuilder(13,17)
        .append(g)
        .append(f)
        .append(data)
        .toHashCode()
```

## Code readability

### Good:

- Very small classes
- Well written to the ability of being testable
- Good and rare usage of interfaces and inheritance
- You wrote tests - this is already a big win

### Arguble:

While your classes remain small and beautiful, some of your methods don't follow the same example.

*Method inside a method*: extract it. A Method usually has to do one thing and not create another one - quite unusual implementation I haven't seen so far:

```
fun<T> path(from: AStarNode<T>,
        to: AStarNode<T>,
        heuristic: ((AStarNode<T>, AStarNode<T>) -> Int),
        cost: ((AStarNode<T>, AStarNode<T>) -> Int)) : Stack<AStarNode<T>> {

/**
 * Reconstructs a path, represented as a [Stack] of [AStarNode]
 * By updating a pointer to a node until the pointer points at null
 */
fun reconstructPath(from: AStarNode<T>) : Stack<AStarNode<T>> {
```

*Very long method*: extract the functionality into other functions / classes. The first method in the example has ~100 lines!

```
fun<T> path(...)
```

When the called instance / method has many parameters, it is always better to *use named params* - like here:

```
class GoapPlanner {
fun plan(actionPool: Collection<GoapAction>, fromState: WorldState, toState: WorldState) = Stack<GoapAction>().apply {
    this.addAll(
            path(
                    GoapNode(fromState, actionPool, null),
                    GoapNode(toState, actionPool, null),
                    { a, b ->
                        (a as GoapNode).worldState.countDifferences((b as GoapNode).worldState)
                    }, { _, b ->
                (b as GoapNode).data?.cost ?: 0
            }
            ).mapNotNull { goapNode ->
                goapNode.data
            }
    )
}
```

## Tests

### Good:

- Short
- Have comments
- Initialisation uses with named params

### Arguable:

- Much duplication for objects and parameters. Its better to define some fields to be used by other tests, which are not that important, but are needed e.g. for initialisation.

  ```
  Pair("HasBread", true)

  Pair("HasMoney", true)
  ```
- Weird assertions

  ```
  assertTrue { !isValid }
  ```
- Assertions which will tell nothing valuable when they fail

  ```
  assertTrue { resultingWorldState == expectedWorldState }
  ```

  The error message would be something like "Expected to be true, but was false". This is worthless! You need to debug to find out WHY they are not equal. 
  There are plenty of methods and other libraries which offer so much better solutions, like [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/). There you could write

  ```
  assertThat(resultingWorldState).isEqualTo(expectedWorldState)
  ```

  and when it fails, it would tell you what was expected, what is the result and what is the difference - much more information.

  Or here:

  ```
      // Assert that the plan is of length 3 and has the correct actions in the correct order
      assertTrue { plan.size == 3 }
      assertTrue { plan.pop() == makeToastAction }
      assertTrue { plan.pop() == getBreadAction }
      assertTrue { plan.pop() == workForMoneyAction }
  ```

  When any of this fails, you don't know which one (besides the *exception on line xy*), what was the real value, what is the difference?
- Naming

  Yes, here we are again. The names of a test are allowed to be longer than usual and should be very explainable. Names like `testSimplePath`,`testComplexPath`, `testComplexPath`, .. tell me nothing!

  Companies have often their own patterns and standards on test names, but my advice would be to start every test with the word 'should'. Like: `should return true, when property xy is bigger than zero`.

  A test should be as simple as it can be and as explainable as it is possible. This includes the name where you can define your case in prose. BTW: [You can use backticks to have a function name with spaces in between.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#function-names)

---

Thanks for reading and I hope I could give you some advice which is actually valuable.

The END

Comment: Great feedback, appreciate the time you must have put in to write this up. 

Whilst I agree with most of your comments, one in particular I am not so sure I agree with:

"Method inside a method: extract it"

I hear a lot of people saying this, and I honestly do not see the benefit of extracting a method that will have a single call site into a private function. My argument for this is;

A) it is not re-used 
B) by moving it you have just made the method with the single call site more complex to understand (you haven't made it any less complex, you've just moved the logic)

Comment: Thanks. To your reply: "B) by moving it you have just made the method with the single call site more complex to understand" I don't get it, how an extracted method - which reduces the outside functions size - makes it more complex. It sounds contradicting. If something is so long I need to encapsulate it in multiple functions which only are interesting in this (method) context - It would even make sence to create an own class for it. Small methods - even iff its just for the lines of code - are always easier to read

Answer (score 2):

I took a single method as example how to make the code simpler:

```
fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction): Boolean {
    // Fold the actions preconditions into an integer representing the unsatisfied variables
    // And return true if the unsatisfied variables are 0 else false
    return action.preconditions.keys.fold(0) { acc, key ->
        acc + when (val prop = this.state[key]) {
            null -> 1
            else -> {
                when (prop == action.preconditions[key]) {
                    true -> 0
                    else -> 1
                }
            }
        }
    } == 0
}
```

One thing I noticed is that the comment describes the implementation.
I don't like these comments since they are better expressed in code.

First step: replace `fold` with `all`.

```
fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction): Boolean {
    return action.preconditions.keys.all { key ->
        when (val prop = this.state[key]) {
            null -> false
            else -> {
                when (prop == action.preconditions[key]) {
                    true -> true
                    else -> false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I replaced `fold` with `all`, since you were effectively using integers to represent a simple boolean decision. By the way, your code had the potential to break unexpectedly when the code would add \$2^{32}\$ times a 1.

Curiously, IntelliJ doesn't notice that the innermost `when` can be made much simpler, so I have to do it manually.

```
fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction): Boolean {
    return action.preconditions.keys.all { key ->
        when (val prop = this.state[key]) {
            null -> false
            else -> prop == action.preconditions[key]
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I extracted the `prop` variable and converted the `when` to an `if`, since I though that IntelliJ might be able to simplify this condition. But it wasn't helpful at all.

```
fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction): Boolean {
    return action.preconditions.keys.all { key ->
        val prop = this.state[key]
        if (prop == null) false else prop == action.preconditions[key]
    }
}
```

Next, I replaced the `if-then-else` with a simple `and`.

```
fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction): Boolean {
    return action.preconditions.keys.all { key ->
        val prop = this.state[key]
        prop != null && prop == action.preconditions[key]
    }
}
```

One thing that I don't like is the `action.preconditions[key]`, since the lookup is unnecessary:

```
fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction): Boolean {
    return action.preconditions.all { entry ->
        val prop = this.state[entry.key]
        prop != null && prop == entry.value
    }
}
```

Now that's much more readable.

I ran the unit tests you provided after each step, to ensure that I didn't make any mistakes. I trusted you to have written good tests, I didn't look at them. In the first try of this refactoring, I had inverted one of the conditions and your tests failed. That was good and encouraging.

One last minification:

```
fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction): Boolean {
    return action.preconditions.all { state[it.key] ?: false == it.value }
}
```

And another:

```
fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction): Boolean {
    return action.preconditions.all { state[it.key] == it.value }
}
```

Same for `countDifferences`:

```
fun WorldState.countDifferences(against: WorldState): Int {
    return against.state.count { state[it.key] != it.value }
}
```

Oh, I cannot resist. If the code is down to a three-liner, a one-liner is possible as well:

```
fun WorldState.countDifferences(against: WorldState) = against.state.count { state[it.key] != it.value }

fun WorldState.isActionValid(action: GoapAction) = action.preconditions.all { state[it.key] == it.value }
```

I normally prefer code that is less than 100 columns wide on the screen, but you seem to like longer lines, so it's ok that there are horizontal scrollbars in this particular code example.

Comment: Great answer, really good points in here

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in `distanceTo`:

```
/**
 * Distance to another node is euclidean and worked out using pythagorean theorem
 */
fun distanceTo(other: CartesianNode): Int {
    val dx = abs(this.x - other.x).toDouble()
    val dy = abs(this.y - other.y).toDouble()
    return round(sqrt(dx * dx) + sqrt(dy * dy)).toInt()
}
```

What you compute here is the Manhattan distance, not the Euclidean distance.

Calculating `sqrt(a * a)` doesn't make sense since it is the same as `a`.

Did you mean `sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)`?

Kotlin has `roundToInt`, which lets you combine the `round` and `toInt` calls.

Here's a unit test for it:

```
@Test
fun cartesianDistance() {
    val node1 = CartesianNode(0, 0, "")
    val node2 = CartesianNode(3000, 4000, "")
    assertEquals(5000, node1.distanceTo(node2))
}
```

Comment: In general, `sqrt(a²)` is the same as **`abs(a)`**.  It's only the same as `a` here because we already did `abs()` when creating `a`.  Of course, the corrected code for Euclidean distance need not (and should not) call `abs()` there, because negatives always square to a positive value.  It's not a language I know, but is there really no provided `hypot()` function such as exists in C?

Comment: Parp! goot spot

Comment: God how did I do that?